# Tomar valor del input HTML y usarlo en consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero tomar el valor del input y usarlo como variable en una consulta MYSQL.
Espero explicarme bien para que se pueda entender mi pregunta.
**Prácticamente todo está en el mismo archivo.**

Tengo lo siguiente.

```
<form name="guardar-registro-check" id="guardar-registro-check" method="POST" action="modelo-check.php" data-aos="fade">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-auto">
                  <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Check</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_check" id="id_check" placeholder="Ingresar ID">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <!-- Parametros que se mandan al if del modelo-check.php -->
                  <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="entrada">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="" value="Check">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

          
          <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = 21 ";
            $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            $cliente = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            /*
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($cliente);
            echo "</pre>";
            */
          ?>

        </div>
```

Quiero pasar el valor del:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_check" id="id_check" placeholder="Ingresar ID">
```

Y usarlo en la parte de la consulta MYSQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = 21 ";
```

Que en vez de ser un número estático **(21)** sea un valor dependiendo del que ingrese el usuario en el input.
Después de la accion del boton.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="" value="Check">
```

Answer (score 1):

La manera mas simple es nativamente del html (sin js)

Para enviar valores desde un formulario a un archivo php, debemos tener en cuenta 5 cosas:

1. Tener un `<form>`
2. Tener los inputs, select, checkbox etc... dentro del `<form>`
3. La etiqueta `<form>` debe teber un atributo `action` con la ruta del .php que van a viajar los datos
4. La etiqueta `<form>` debe tener un atributo `method` que definimos como viajan los datos: `GET` o `POST`
5. Los inputs deben tener su atributo `name` para ser identificado por el receptor

Si enviamos un simple formulario con destino a `example.php` sería de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="example.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="txtPrueba">
</form>
```

Y el archivo example.php

```
<?php
//validamos por un if: si la variable que recibimos por POST llamada txtPrueba está asignada
if(isset($_POST['txtPrueba'])){
    //Recibimos el valor del input
    //Para dejarlo en una variable sería:
    $texto = $_POST['txtPrueba'];
}else{
    //No se recibió valor del input
}
```

Respondiendo a tu caso:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id_check'])){
        $id_check = $_POST['id_check'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = $id_check";
        $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
        $cliente = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        /*
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($cliente);
        echo "</pre>";
        */
    }
?>
```

Debo mencionar que la manera que se está ejecutando la query es muy vulnerable, pero no es malo para comenzar a practicar la lógica.

Comment: Como me recomendarías para hacer la query mas segura.

Comment: te recomiendo ver esta pregunta [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/47512)